# Data binding to ComboBox in c#.net

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to make a windows application for Library Management.
I'm trying to bind the data generated by `SQLQuery` to `comboBoxBranch`, but its only showing `--Select--` in the options. Is there anything wrong with following code?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bindBranch();
}

private void bindBranch()
{
    OleDbCommand SQLQuery = new OleDbCommand();
    string sqlQueryString = "Select br_id from branch";
    DataTable data = null;

    SQLQuery.Connection = null;
    OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = null;
    try
    {
        SQLQuery.CommandText = sqlQueryString;
        SQLQuery.Connection = database;
        data = new DataTable();
        dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(SQLQuery);
        dataAdapter.Fill(data);
        comboBoxBranch.DisplayMember = "br_id";                
        DataRow dr = data.NewRow();
        dr[0] = "--Select--";
        data.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
        comboBoxBranch.DataSource = data;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Is there anything else I need to add to some other pages to make this work?

Comment: Don't eat the exception.  Use the Debugger to verify your data table is filled with something.  It sounds like it doesn't.

Comment: Can you check if the datatable has data in it. i don't think it has the required data.

Comment: How can i check that? I'm new to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind data like this.

```
comboBoxBranch.DataSource = new BindingSource { DataSource = data };
comboBoxBranch.DisplayMember = "br_id";
comboBoxBranch.ValueMember = //> something else
```

Comment: Set the DataSource property last to avoid possible binding errors and avoid multiple refreshing calls by the control.

Comment: You can check two things. 
1)What is returning from db? Is your data count > 0 ?  
2)I'm not sure but combobox may needs key-value pair. Basically you only have DisplayMember but not have ValueMember. Also you can use same member to bind ValueMember like comboBoxBranch.ValueMember = "br_id"; I would suggest to try it.